# Can't SSH into Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, error-code

I was able to successfully SSH into the Google Cloud VM I had set up yesterday, but today for some reason I can't, and I didn't mess with any of the settings, especially not the Firewall settings. It keeps giving me these errors now:

*Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 4003
Reason: failed to connect to backend
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.*

Then when I click on "Connect without Identity-Aware Proxy" I get the following error:

*Connection Failed
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.*

I don't know what happened. Yesterday it was working fine and now it's not.

Comment: Is the target VM running Linux, Windows or something else?  What specific command are you running at your workstation where you see the error?  Where is your source workstation (is it a physical workstation on premises or a cloud hosted virtual machine)?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on Google Cloud, I am VM instances and I try to connect by SSH by clicking on SSH under Connect

Comment: Did you modify in any way the Compute Engine instance?  For example, if you spin up a brand new instance of an Ubuntu 16.04 with default settings, are you able to SSH into it from the GCP Console by clicking the SSH Connect button?

Comment: All I did was install an execution server that I've been trying to get to work, including being secure.

Comment: This can happen if `sshd` is messed up (and port 22 is fine, but nothing is running at it) or port 22 is being blocked. Google has an article up on debugging SSH issues in GCP. Please follow these steps and update your post when you have finished: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Answer (score 2):

At first, try to disable Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy and connect to the VM instance via web Console.

After that, check logs:

- Go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on NAME_OF_YOUR_VM -> at the `VM instance details` find section **Logs** and click on `Serial port 1 (console)`
- Reboot your VM instance.
- Check full boot log for any errors or/and warnings.

If your VM instance doesn't start up verify that your disk has a valid file system and a valid master boot record (MBR) by following the documentation [General troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances).

If you found errors/warning related to disk space you can try to resize it accordingly to the documentation [Resizing a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd), also accordingly to the article [Recovering an inaccessible instance or a full boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#inaccessible_instance):

> If an instance is completely out of disk space or if it is not running
> a Linux guest environment, then automatically resizing your root
> filesystem isn't possible, even after you've increased the size of the
> persistent disk that backs it. If you can't connect to your instance,
> or your boot disk is full and you can't resize it, you must create a
> new instance and recreate the boot disk from a snapshot to resize it.

Otherwise try get access to your VM instance via serial console :

- [Enable serial console connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

  ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
  ```

  or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`
- Create temporary user and password to login: shutdown your VM and set a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

  ```
    useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
    echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
  ```

  and then start your VM.
- [Connect to your VM via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

  ```
    gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
  ```

  or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`
- Check what went wrong.
- [Disable access via serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

  ```
    gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
    --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
  ```

  or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`. Keep in mind that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

  > **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
  > restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
  > serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
  > instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
  > they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
  > instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
  > and specific ports.

If you weren't able to connect via serial console, try follow the documentation [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) section [Inspect the VM instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#inspect_vm) and inspect the disk of your VM on another VM. Same way you can transfer your data to another working VM instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had had the same issue while running composer update.

In my case an rebooting of the VM-Instance has solved it.

Comment: How do you reboot a VM-Instance? And did you lose any of your files in your home directory when you rebooted your VM-Instance?

Comment: Having struggled with the problem for 50 minutes, this simple thing just worked...

Answer (score 0):

Beased on these error messages, I guess that your project has [Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) enabled](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/iap?_ga=2.247741252.257317006.1591558775-1485130468.1582663855), which sometimes may affect the ability to SSH into an instance, depending on the configuration.

In order to rule out this, you may try the following:

- [Create the firewall rules for allowing IAP to connect to your instances](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#preparing_your_project_for_tcp_forwarding)
- [Grant the necessary permissions to use IAP](http://%20https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#grant-permission)
- [Tunnel the SSH connection through IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#tunneling_ssh_connections)

Comment: It seems like even after creating new rule the IAP not getting acivated. Getting an warning on the ssh connection tab of IAP page