# Google Compute Engine VM Error 4003 logging back in with python-flask

Tags: python, nginx, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running Ubuntu 18.04,
and am following this tutorial to make a flask server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

And if I log off, and try to log back in,
I am unable to SSH into my instance,
and it give me this error:

```
Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 4003
Reason: failed to connect to backend
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.
```

And I have tried creating an instance from an image of the original.
I've tried adjusting my firewall, and then ssh into another port.
I've tried to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy.

And it happens every time I set up a new machine AFTER I set up Nginx.

There are some other people on here who have encountered the same problem like [Error 4003: can't ssh login into the instance that i created in google cloud platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58450539/error-4003-cant-ssh-login-into-the-instance-that-i-created-in-google-cloud-pla)
and
[Can't SSH into Google Cloud VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310291/cant-ssh-into-google-cloud-vm)

but neither thread has really any helpful answers. Has anyone who's encountered this been able to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the firewall.
I ufw, but forgot to allow ssh connections, and I locked myself out.

I created an entirely new machine, and allowed 22 and ssh from the get go.